# Counting the number of scanner inputs by a user without using a loop

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm not supposed to use loops for this assignment. Just if/else statements.

I'm trying to get the number of inputs(up to a maximum of 8 inputs) from the scanner and adding them to a counter.

For example, if the user enters 1 3 6 4, the counter should equal 4.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyPredictionsOfCodeBehaviour {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter some numbers between 1 and 8.");
        int counter = userInput.nextInt();
        System.out.println(counter);
        userInput.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Currently your program only reads **one** `int` (`userInput.nextInt()`). You may add some kind of loop in order to read all available integer. Alternatively use a different approach like first interpreting the input as `String`, using `userInput.nextLine()`. After that you may extract all integer using regex matching or other methods of `String` like `String.split(" ")`. You'll need the regex approach for complicated input- The splitting thing will work if input stays simple as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scan the entire input line as a string instead, split by space and read the resulting array's length

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter some numbers between 1 and 8.");
    String input = userInput.nextLine(); //Read input as string
    System.out.println(input.split(" ").length); //Count inputs
    userInput.close();
}
```

You can use any other delimiter in `split()` if you like.